# Is it possible to hide title bar of Firefox 22 in OS X 10.8.4

Tags: macos, firefox

Is there any way to hide or remove Firefox 22 title bar in OS X 10.8.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no

It has been a [bug](http://kb.mozillazine.org/browser.fullscreen.autohide) since firefox 13
Even though autohide is set to 'true' the toolbars won't hide in fullscreen.

Best option is to go to view -> Toolbars and uncheck the toolbars in the top menu
But this leaves the 'tab toolbar'

So if you really want to hide the toolbars you should open the page in a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

No, not in FF 22, [that feature will be introduced in Firefox 28](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=625989).